# Вывод Apache в интернет

Tags: windows, apache, сервер, веб-сервер, windows-server-2012

Мне нужно вывести Apache в интернет (ну или сайт). Стоит Apache на Windows Server 2012 , cо статическим ip адресом, и с открытым портом 80 (8080 недоступен, потому что он используется для вода на терминал (роутер)). Что надо перенастроить в апаче и в конфиге hosts ?

Comment: Если вы обращаясь по ip адресу уже попадаете на ссвой сайт, то настраивать на винде больше ничего не нужно. Вам надо покупать (или редактировать существующее) доменное имя. И в настройках DNS указывать ip сервера в A записи(ях)

Comment: @Mike Так. У меня есть домен. Там я указал мой ip сервера в A записях. Потом, в файле httpd-vhost что вводить что бы он был в интернете? А в файле hosts надо вводить в первый столбик ip адрес сервера или локальный? а во втором сам домен?

Comment: Файл hosts отвечает за определение ip по имени на одной конкретной машине, т.е. на самом сервере и в том случае если этой информации нет в DNS. Т.е. вам он не нужен. Для начала убедитесь что DNS настроена правильно и отдает нужный адрес (например ping имя, оно напишет что пингую адрес такой то). Если работает - вбиваете в браузере и смотрите что скажет и появится ли в логах апача. Вот если в логах апача появляется но выдает не ту страницу или ошибки - тогда смотрите конфиги апача

Comment: @mike что надо менять в настройках апача?

Comment: А что он сейчас говорит когда пытаетесь зайти на свой сайт ? А вообще примеров конфигов и интернете полным полно плюс к этому они с апачем поставляются